# Can't reach PC over network until it pings me

Tags: networking, router, ping

I have two Ubuntu PC's in my setup.  PC A is wired into the home router.  PC B is wireless.  When I reboot PC A, I can't ping PC B until PC B pings PC A.  After that it works just fine.
Also I think other network commands (ssh, etc) will make the host reachable also.

After PC A reboots, a ping to PC B says 'Destination Host Unreachable', but it can reach the internet and other PC's on the router.

Any ideas on what to check?

Comment: I'd check your router settings for something called "Wireless Isolation" or "AP isolated mode". If this setting is enabled, wireless clients can only connect to the router, but not to other machines.

Comment: See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/521928) for answer.